# Memory leaks in frame scripts (e10s)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, multiprocessing

I'm not sure how to handle event listeners and other listeners in a frame script.

I have the following code (shortened):

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadFrameScript("aFrameScript.js", true);
```

that is after some time is followed by the call

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.removeDelayedFrameScript("aFrameScript.js");
```

Inside that aFrameScript.js I add various DOM event listeners and also QI the docShell to webNavigation and webProgress to add web progress and session history listeners.

The question is should I remove DOM event listeners and/or web progress and session history listeners before calling removeDelayedFrameScript()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is should I remove DOM event listeners and/or web progress and session history listeners before calling removeDelayedFrameScript()?

Yes, calling `removeDelayedFrameScript` merely prevents the script from being added to new browser windows, it does not remove the script from windows which are already open.